# Балансировка ASP.NET MVC приложения. Слетает авторизация, если более одного бекенда

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nginx, iis

Опишу ситуацию.
Имеется ASP.NET MVC приложение, достаточно старое, для авторизации используется form authentication.

Пытаюсь решить проблему деплоя кода на prod окружение. Сейчас при публикации ASP.NET MVC приложения оно становится недоступным от 10 секунд до нескольких минут (не очень понимаю, почему так долго, если честно).
Вопрос не по теме, может быть есть решения для этой проблемы от Microsoft?

Поэтому перед IIS сервером (перед тестовым окружением, для начала) поставил nginx, настроил на нем upstream и указал текущий сервер в качестве бекенда.
Протестировал - все работает.
Далее, развернул еще одно окружение с ASP.NET MVC приложением на другой виртуальной машине и добавил его адрес в upstream.
То есть, dns всегда ведет на nginx, а он уже проксирует запросы то на один, то на другой север обычным round robin. Все заработало корректно, авторизовавшись, на адресе v2.domain.ru, все корректно работает, даже если мы заменяем/включаем/отключаем backend'ы, прописанные в upstream.

Далее, настроил все это в teamcity и заменил домен v2.domain.ru на dev.domain.ru, поскольку это "официальное" тестовое окружение. Естественно, перед этим создал приложения 1.dev и 2.dev для публикации двух экземпляров.
Запускаю deploy - все работает, запросы чередуются, но после авторизации на сайте, начинает грузиться правильная страница, а вот контент в нее загружается уже такой, будто мы не авторизованы.

Тесты показали, что если настроить, что dev.domain.ru всегда ведет на 1.dev.domain.ru - все работает корректно. Если меняем, чтобы запросы шли на 2.dev.domain.ru - авторизация сразу слетает. Аналогично, если наоборот.

Путем изучения логики авторизации понял, что токен .ASPXAUTH в куках - это зашифрованный UserName при помощи ключа, которым является machineKey, который по умолчанию генерируется автоматически для каждого приложения в iis.

Тогда логично, почему слетает аутентификация на dev окружении и не понятно, почему она не слетает до сих пор на v2 окружении.

Сгенерировал machineKey вручную, отключил автогенерацию, добавил его в web.config и переопубликовал 1.dev и 2.dev приложения.
При этом, ничего не изменилось.

Далее, чтобы убедиться, что токен действительно корректный и может работать с обоими приложениями, сделал следующее:

- Открыл оба приложения 1.dev.domain.ru и 2.dev.domain.ru и авторизовался в обоих
- Взял куку .ASPXAUTH первого приложения и перезаписал через консоль браузера ее во второе приложение вместе с датой окончания. Авторизация сохранилась и продолжила работать. При этом, если изменить, например, один символ, авторизация, естественно, слетает.

И теперь вопрос - что я делаю не так и почему не работает dev окружение и каким вообще образом работает v2 окружение?

**PS:** проекты 1.v2 и 1.dev расположены на VM1, а 2.v2 и 2.dev - на VM2. То есть окружения у них идентичные.

В каждом IIS приложении в Bindings прописаны адреса:

- X.dev.domain.ru
- dev.domain.ru
  где X - 1 или 2 в зависимости от машины.

Конфиг nginx настроен как proxy_pass на upstream и содержит следующие настройки:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://dev;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
}
```

Comment: Сразу хочу заметить, что в текущих IIS приложениях, которые 1.v2 и 2.v2 я пробовал прописать 1.dev и 2.dev, соответственно. И перенастраивал dns на эти приложения. После этого dev.domain.ru работал корректно. То есть какая-то магия в этих приложениях. В одних что-то есть, а в других нет.

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash

Comment: @norbornen сейчас протестирую, но это не решает концептуальную проблему. Я хочу, чтобы в то время, когда заливаю код на один сервер, запросы шли на второй и при этом не требовало у пользователя заново авторизоваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена.

У меня в некоторых местах кода была операция `WebSecurity.Logout()`, если `User.UserInRole(..)` выполнялся, генерируя исключение.
То есть сам создал себе проблему)

Просто закомментировал строку и все заработало.
Вопрос только в том, почему оно там падает и почему не падало на v2 окружении.